# why "ps -ef -u root -U root" also displays user processes?

Tags: process, ps

```
ps -ef -u root -U root
```

Also displays processes whose user is not root (the current user). Can someone explain me why ?

```
-u : EUID

-U : RUID
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you use `-e` option, it causes `ps` select all processes.

POSIX define [ps -e](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html#tag_20_96_04) as:

```
-e
Write information for all processes (Equivalent to -A.)
```

Comment: Ok, I thought adding a filter would... filter more. Thanks

Comment: @PerrierCitror: Use `-u` and `-U` alone, they are not combination with `-e`.